# Ruby - System Command - ps aux

Tags: ruby, linux

So I'm trying to find the PID of any process which has the word "control" in it.  I'm in ruby on linux.  This is the basic code so far

```
`ps aux | grep control`
```

If I run that in ruby, all the distinct lines that would come back when run in linux, get concatenated into one long string.  How can I have ruby read the results in as a list, instead of one long string?

Comment: I don't know ruby, but if all you want are the pids you may want to consider the command `pgrep -f control` which will do much the same as your command but without the extra subshell and with just the PIDs in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split it on the newline characters like so:

```
lines = (`ps aux | grep control`).split(/\n/)
```

With that done you can iterate over them, select things out using a regex, etc..

Comment: If you don't want the command itself to appear there, you can write `lines = (\`ps aux | grep [c]ontrol\`).split(/\n/)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on linux, you could could examine the /proc filesystem.  There are /proc// directories, and /proc//cmdline has the command line.

Comment: The documentation http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html helped me to understand that comment.